# Browser opens, but never goes to URL using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, junit

I want to write couple of tests for a web page with Selenium and jUnit4, but I can't figure out how to make Firefox open the URL I need. Without System.setProperty(...) I'm getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver.` and browser never opens. Yet if I implement it **the browser does open** on a default start "new page", but the line `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` and further **never executes**.
Below is the simplest code version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Main {
static String URL = "http://www.google.com";
static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    //Following code never executes
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //I'm not sure if this is how I'm supposed to open URL, but I never had this code executed.
    driver.get(URL);

    driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**:
These links were helpful to solve the problem of proper geckodriver installation.
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

http://learn-automation.com/use-firefox-selenium-using-geckodriver-selenium-3/

Comment: Do you get an Error, or doesn't it just not go to the site? I'm assuming you've stepped through this code to see what happens before `driver.quit()` is called

Comment: I've checked with simple sout()'s, the code after "new FirefoxDriver" never executes.

Comment: I believe Narendra's answer is your issue. You have to download the `geckodriver` and point to that, not `firefox.exe`. Basically, your code is running `firefox.exe` but doesn't know how to drive it.

Comment: Make sure FF and the selenium drivers are all up-to-date and you have installed them correctly. This behavior is indicative of mismatched versions or bad install in some way.

Comment: @JeffC I'm running latest versions of both

Comment: Then it's likely that something isn't installed correctly. I would go back to the installation and use guide and double check everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you need to set `geckodriver.exe` path instead of `firefox.exe` in this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
```

So just replace `geckodriver.exe` path and try

Comment: You're right, I downloaded latest version of geckodriver from here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases